# How many ways to make a connected graph using 4, 5, 6 edges?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory

How can/how many ways can you make a connected graph that has 5 vertices using 4, 5, 6 edges?

I'm not sure how it would look like for 4 edges. Can you draw a diagram?

Comment: If it has 4 edges, it must be a tree, and that is well studied.

Answer (score 1):

If your graph has $4$ edges, it must be a *tree* (a *tree* is a graph with no cycles). To see this, notice that if it had a $5$-cycle it would have $5$ edges, if it had a $4$-cycle it would have no edge connecting to the vertex outside the cycle, and if it had a $3$-cycle it would be disconnected, either because the $4$th edge connects the two other vertices and we have two connected components, or the $4$th edge connects one of the two other vertices to our $3$-cycle and the fifth point would be disconnected. Conversely, any connected tree with $5$ vertices has four edges (any connected tree with $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges ; you can prove this easily by induction on $n$).

Now to build all possible trees, start with one vertex $v_0$, and decide how many vertices will be "at distance $1$" of $v_0$ (i.e. those whose shortest path to $v_0$ consists of one edge), then those "at distance $2$", and so on. In other words, look at all partitions of $5$ where two partitions differing by commutativity of addition are considered distinct ; then put edges between all pairs of vertices $(v,v')$ for which the difference between the distance $d(v,v_0)$ and $d(v',v_0)$ is $\pm 1$.

After doing this list, you'll find only three pairwise non-isomorphic graphs, namely the line ($\cdot - \cdot - \cdot - \cdot - \cdot$), this ($\cdot - \cdot - \cdot < :$) and the star graph on $5$ vertices (which looks like $+$).

If it has $5$ vertices and $5$ edges, you already know what to do if the graph has no cycles ; repeat the previous procedure. Then you can distinguish cases where it has a $3$-cycle, $4$-cycle and $5$-cycle ; $5$-cycle and $4$-cycle are easy (there is only one graph in each case), and for a $3$-cycle there are only two ways of making it connected ; either you link the two remaining vertices by an edge or not.

For $5$ vertices and $6$ edges, you're starting to have too many edges, so it's easier to count "backwards" ; we'll look for the graphs which are *not* connected. You clearly must have at most two connected components (check this), and if your two connected components have $(3,2)$ vertices, then the graph has $3$ or $4$ edges ; so our components must have $(4,1)$ vertices. But then there is only one case ; the complete graph $K_4$ together with an extra point. So all graphs with $5$ vertices and $6$ edges (except $K_4$ with an extra point) are connected.

Hope that helps,

Comment: replying to the "partitions of 5" section. "the partitions of 5 where two partition differ by communtativity of addition are considered distinct" are: 5, 2+3, 3+2, 1+4, 4+1, 1+1+3, 1+3+1,3+1+1, 2+2+1, 1+2+2, 2+1+2 = 11 total. By "between the distance d(v, v0) and d(v',v0) is +/-1, do you mean partitions like 2+2+1 and 3+1+1?

Comment: Does that mean for 5 vertices/4 edges, there are 3 configurations; for 5 vertices/5 edges there are 4 configurations; for 5 vertices/6 edges there are 10 configurations? 17 configurations total?

Comment: @MathisLife : In the counting, partitions have nothing to do with the distance. You use the distance to put edges between pairs of vertices which satisfy the distance condition ; be aware that you shouldn't pick those choices which give you a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

For $4$ edges:
$${\rm X}\qquad {\rm W}\qquad \vdash$$

Answer (score 0):

The diagram would be like
[image]

For an edge to be placed remember that you must choose $2$ vertices and be careful about bijection, by that i mean that if you do not label the vertices this two graphs (see below) are identical.
[image]

**Edit:**
As commented, because they are just a few, you can iterate all the ways (without order i.e. $2+2+2+1+1=2+1+2+2+1=\ldots =1+1+2+2+2$) you can put a number in the degrees of your graph by recalling $\sum _{v\in V}\deg(v)=2|E|$. In the diagram above is the graph with degrees $2,2,2,1,1$.
 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Does that mean that there is only one way to make a connected graph with 5 vertices using only 4 edges?

Comment: Nop, it is just one diagram. There are more.

Comment: How would I find them?

Comment: @Phicar : How did you make the images? I can use TikZ but if you really did it by "TikZ"-hand I must say you are not a lazy person.

Comment: @MathisLife mmmm try by degree. Recall $\sum _{v\in G}deg(v)=2|E|$, in your case $deg(v_1)+deg(v_2)+deg(v_3)+deg(v_4)+deg(v_5)=8$ there are a few cases because of the non bijection allowed. I thought you were unable to find just one.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Nop, i did not. I used ipe tool, it is awesome. http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/ ... BtW, i am very lazy ;).

Comment: A good mathematician is a lazy mathematician who works hard.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: It is really easy in TikZ with the graphs library. With `\tikzset{graphs/nodes={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt}}` in the preamble, the first graph is just `\tikz \graph { / -- / -- / -- / -- /};` and the second one is `\tikz \graph { / -- / -- c/ -- d/ -- /; c--[out=60,in=120] d};`